# Ink Filepicker convert - The FPFile could not be converted with the requested parameters

Tags: filepicker.io

I have an application setup in Filepicker. This application uploads directly to my S3 bucket. The initial pickAndStore() function works well. The follow up convert function always fails with the 403 error "The FPFile could not be converted with the requested parameters". I have the following code:

```
try {
    filepicker.setKey(apiKey);
    filepicker.pickAndStore(
        {
            extensions : [ '.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png' ],
            container  : 'modal',
            services   : [ 'COMPUTER', 'WEBCAM', 'PICASA', 'INSTAGRAM', 'FACEBOOK', 'DROPBOX' ],
            policy     : policy,
            signature  : signature,
         },
         {
            location   : 'S3',
            multiple   : false,
            path       : path,
         }, 
         function(InkBlobs){
             filepicker.convert(
                 InkBlobs[0], 
                 {
                     width      : 150,
                     height     : 150,
                     fit        : 'max',
                     align      : 'faces',
                     format     : 'png',
                     policy     : policy,
                     signature  : signature,
                  }, 
                  {
                      location   : 'S3',
                      path       : response.path + fileName + '.png',
                  }, 
                  function(InkBlob) {
                      console.log(InkBlob);
                  }, 
                  function(FPError) {
                      console.log(FPError);
                  }
              );

          },
          function(InkBlobs){
              console.log(JSON.stringify(InkBlobs));
          }
      );
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.toString());
  }
```

The error handler function is always called. The raw POST response is...

> "Invalid response when trying to read from
>   http://res.cloudinary.com/filepicker-io/image/fetch/a_exif,c_limit,f_png,g_face,h_150,w_150/https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/"

...with the rest of my credentials appended. The debug handler returns the previously mentioned message with the moreInfo parameter pointing to a URL "https://developers.filepicker.io/answers/jsErrors/142" which has no content on it about the error.

I thought the problem might be that using S3 directly means the file is not present on the Filepicker system to convert. I tried using the standard pick() function without any S3 uploading and then converting the resulting InkBlob. That produced exactly the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem at the moment is that the length of the URL being used in the convert function is too long for the web service filepicker uses to do the conversion. It is too long because the policy/signature are appended. There does not appear to be a way to fix this problem at present. Therefore you cannot store to S3 using the security features with the convert function.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the error is in the use of faces and fit max. When using faces, you can only set fit to crop.

The interpretation in the command above is to find the faces, but set the image to fit the max allowed size.

Comment: Hi Raul. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make any difference to the response. The same 400 BAD REQUEST is returned from your servers. "[uuid=CF627296031D4DAC] Invalid response when trying to read from http://res.cloudinary.com/filepicker-io/image/fetch/a_exif,c_fill,f_png,g_face,h_150,w_150/https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/REMOVED?policy=REMOVED&signature=REMOVED". I have tried it with completely default settings on the convert, also with no success. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "path" option in the policy.

Specifying the path in the policy works well for pickAndStore(), though if you specify a path in your policy for convert, filepicker will give you a 403 error adressing the conversion parameters. Seems like the API won't know if it's the source or destination path.